# PHP Stops loading on html, but still processes on server

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I am using a form with a file input to submit an excel file and upload the data into a MySQL database. The script imports everything just fine.

Only problem is that the process seems to timeout on the client browser, even though it  seems to continue it's process on the server, but it seems to timeout on the client browser. I have already added all the common fixes, I.E.:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
set_time_limit(0);      
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

I am currently using a `flush();` and `ob_end_flush();` to output a message every 1000 records that get scanned for upload.

Unfortunately, after exactly 2 minutes, the page stops loading.

On the flip side, it does continue to upload the records all records get scanned and uploaded regardless of the page. This leads me to believe that somehow the request is continuing to process on the web server, but somehow the browser stops getting info from the server after a certain amount of time. Based on my calculations, the browser stops getting the request after exactly 2 minutes.

I have tried this on both Internet Explorer and Chrome and I get the same result. I have not made any changes to the php.ini file for the security reasons.

Using Old Zend Server with Apache2.

Comment: is PHP.ini interfering with your ability to change these settings?

Comment: "I have not made any changes to the php.ini file for the security reasons."  What security reasons would prevent you from configuring your server?

Comment: What is your stack? Are you on Centos with apache or something else?

Comment: I doubt it, since the server is still processing the data on it's in. Although I chose not to adjust the php.ini document so that not ALL the pages have an unlimited load time, etc.

Comment: Old Zend Server version 6, with Apache